# encryption with single key in c#

Tags: c#, encryption

i have a code in c# that encrypt and decrypt .txt file. but i need to encrypt and decrypt files with any extension like pdf, zip, jpg etc..

i searched ant tried to find stream encryption but i couldnt find any..

i am trying following code from [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010) . i changed file path and put some pdf or ppt. it works correctly but i can not open decrypted file.

```
  using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace CSEncryptDecrypt
{
   class Class1
   {
      //  Call this function to remove the key from memory after use for security
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("KERNEL32.DLL", EntryPoint="RtlZeroMemory")]
      public static extern bool ZeroMemory(IntPtr Destination, int Length);

      // Function to Generate a 64 bits Key.
      static string GenerateKey() 
      {
         // Create an instance of Symetric Algorithm. Key and IV is generated automatically.
         DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto =(DESCryptoServiceProvider)DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();

         // Use the Automatically generated key for Encryption. 
         return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
      }

      static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename,
         string sOutputFilename, 
         string sKey) 
      {
         FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename, 
            FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read);

         FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, 
            FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write);
         DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
         DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
         DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
         ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
         CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, 
            desencrypt, 
            CryptoStreamMode.Write); 

         byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
         fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
         cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
         cryptostream.Close();
         fsInput.Close();
         fsEncrypted.Close();
      }

      static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename, 
         string sOutputFilename,
         string sKey)
      {
         DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
         //A 64 bit key and IV is required for this provider.
         //Set secret key For DES algorithm.
         DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
         //Set initialization vector.
         DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

         //Create a file stream to read the encrypted file back.
         FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename, 
            FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read);
         //Create a DES decryptor from the DES instance.
         ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
         //Create crypto stream set to read and do a 
         //DES decryption transform on incoming bytes.
         CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread, 
            desdecrypt,
            CryptoStreamMode.Read);
         //Print the contents of the decrypted file.
         StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
         fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
         fsDecrypted.Flush();
         fsDecrypted.Close();
      } 

      static void Main()
      {
         // Must be 64 bits, 8 bytes.
         // Distribute this key to the user who will decrypt this file.
         string sSecretKey;

         // Get the Key for the file to Encrypt.
         sSecretKey = GenerateKey();

         // For additional security Pin the key.
         GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc( sSecretKey,GCHandleType.Pinned );

         // Encrypt the file.        
         EncryptFile(@"C:\MyData.txt", 
            @"C:\Encrypted.txt", 
            sSecretKey);

         // Decrypt the file.
         DecryptFile(@"C:\Encrypted.txt", 
            @"C:\Decrypted.txt", 
            sSecretKey);

         // Remove the Key from memory. 
         ZeroMemory(gch.AddrOfPinnedObject(), sSecretKey.Length * 2);
         gch.Free();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "cannot open decrypted file"? Do you get an error or exception or something? I don't see any content specific handling either, the type of file should not matter much.

Comment: code works perfectly when i try to encrypt pdf file. it creates encrypted pdf file and after it is decrypted. when i try to open newly created decrypted file i get an error. "there was an error opening this document. the file is damaged and could not be repaired."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for responses. i found the reason. i should use filestream not the streamwriter in the decryptFile function

Answer (score -1):

following routine I'm using to serialize objects securely. 
Maybe it can help you to understand how stream encryption works:

```
public bool Save(string filename, object toSerialize)
    {

        byte[] SALT = new byte[]
        {0x26, 0xdc, 0xff, 0x00, 0xad, 0xed, 0x7a, 0xee, 0xc5, 0xfe, 0x07, 0xaf, 0x4d, 0x08, 0x22, 0x3c};

        string EncryptionKey = "MYPASSWORD";

        //basic serialization
        IFormatter form = new BinaryFormatter();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        form.Serialize(stream, toSerialize);

        //cryptography preparation
        var alg = new RijndaelManaged();
        var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, SALT);
        alg.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        alg.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

        stream.Position = 0;
        //cryptorgraphy serialization
        var encStream = new MemoryStream();
        var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encStream, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(stream.ToArray(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

        var outputFileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        outputFileStream.Write(encStream.ToArray(), 0, (int)encStream.Length);
        outputFileStream.Close();


        return true;
    }
```

I can also put you sources to deserialize encrypted stream.

Comment: So stream encryption works by writing to a `CryptoStream` with parent `MemoryStream` and then using `stream.ToArray()` and write the resulting byte array to another stream? And the input was an object that is serialized instead of a binary file?

Comment: yes, above routine is only showes how to use CryptoStream to make serialized object secured. But you can write any stream to cryptoStream. In my case I'm writing stream of serialized object but also you can write file stream.